# How to raise exception in a method that returns a tuple?

Tags: python, mocking

I have the following method `is_device_subscription_valid` that I would like to test, when an exception has been raised.

```
            try:
                (
                    is_success,
                    r_nano,
                ) = await sub_service.is_device_subscription_valid(receipt.receipt)
            except (ConnectionError, OperationalError, ProtocolError):
                issues_list.append((device.id, receipt.expires_at))
```

```
    @patch("service.sub_ios_service.SubscriptionService.is_device_subscription_valid")
    async def test_invalid_premium_users(self, mock_error, client):
        mock_error.return_value.raiseError.side_effect = Mock(
            side_effect=ConnectionError("Test"), return_value=("bla", "bla")
        )
        await DailyAccessCleanup().cleanup()
```

However instead of raising an exception through side effects I get

```
>               (
                    is_success,
                    r_nano,
                ) = await sub_service.is_device_subscription_valid(receipt.receipt)
E               ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

It shouldn't matter though what values are returned, when it should raise an exception.

Here is the proof that the method is caught by the patch, hence the path is correct.

[image]

Comment: Well, you patched an object but didn't provide `return_value`. Hence return_value of the patched object will be None and this would be the reason, why python is not able to unpack tuples... there is simply not enough values to unpack ;-)

Comment: Is this what you mean? `mock_error.return_value = "x", "y"` and `mock_error.raiseError.side_effect = Mock(side_effect=ConnectionError("Test"))`?  This doesn't raise any exception.

Comment: `@patch("service.sub_ios_service.SubscriptionService.is_device_subscription_valid", return_value=('a','b'))` something along these lines. Furthermore, if you want to test for exception  take a look at https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions

Comment: The suggested approach is to eliminate ` ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`. But if you want the method itself to raise exeception then I don't think you need to mock anything but provide wrong values to your function.

Comment: No, that didn't work. Neither is the second suggestion workable. You can't expect a method to raise a ConnectionError by providing wrong values to the function.

Comment: Maybe this can help you then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314953/pytest-how-to-force-raising-exceptions-during-unit-testing